# Ways of solving the following recurrence relation system.

Tags: recurrence-relations

Consider the following system of linear recurrence relations.

$$\begin{aligned} p_n &= a \cdot p_{n-1} - c_{n-1}\\ c_{n-1} &= p_{n-1} - b \cdot p_{n-2} + c_{n-2}\end{aligned}$$

with $p_0 = 1$ and $c_1 = 1$.

I've tried to represent $p_n$ as a finite linear combination of $p_{k}, k < n$, but this doesn't work for me. Maybe there is any chance to represent the final solution?

Any ideas?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I thought about it, but there are a different number of variables in these two equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

It's helpful to have the indices line up, so let's rewrite this as

$$
\begin{aligned}
p_n &= a p_{n-1} - c_{n-1} \\
c_n &= p_n - b p_{n-1} + c_{n-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Of course, we can use the known definition of $p_n$ to get

$$
\begin{aligned}
p_n &= a p_{n-1} - c_{n-1} \\
c_n &= (a-b) p_{n-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

It's helpful to keep track of all this in a matrix, as such:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
p_{n} \\ c_{n}
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -1 \\ a-b & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
p_{n-1} \\ c_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Do you see where to go from here? You'll want to consider powers of this $2 \times 2$ matrix applied to your initial condition $\begin{pmatrix} p_1 \\ c_1 \end{pmatrix}$. Note also that you were *given* $p_0$, so you'll need to compute $p_1$ by hand to get going.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: and Cayley-Hamilton for your square matrix gives separate recurrences for $c_n$  and for $p_n.$  See the other answer for  $p_n$

Answer (score 4):

Note that
\begin{align}
p_n-p_{n-1} &= (ap_{n-1}-c_{n-1})-(ap_{n-2}-c_{n-2})\\
&=a(p_{n-1}-p_{n-2})-(p_{n-1}-bp_{n-2})\\
\implies p_n&=ap_{n-1}+(b-a)p_{n-2}
\end{align}
Now use the standard way to solve recursions of this form (by solving the corresponding quadratic equation).

Comment: we also get such a recurrence for $c_i$ from Cayley-Hamilton for the matrix in the other answer. Same coefficients  as for $p_i$

Comment: @WillJagy, That's right, but using such a concept for solving a recursion as simple as this, is too much.